# Scrapy CrawlSpider - add meta data to request

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm working on a `CrawlSpider` which gets multiple `Domain` objects (it contains `main_url` and `name` - domain name). Then it crawls whole page for every `Domain` object.

So there is a `Domain` with `main_url = 'http://www.example.com'` and `name = 'example.com'`. I need to get this `domain` object for every response of this domain. So `http://www.example.com`, `http://www.example.com/x`, `http://www.example.com/x/x/y/` etc.

So everytime I'm parsing response from this domain, I get particular `Domain` object.

The problem is that it is not doable inside `rules = ()`

```
class MainSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'main_spider' 
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_item', follow=True,),
    )

    def start_requests(self):
        for d in Domain.objects.all():
            self.allowed_domains.append(d.name)
            yield scrapy.Request(d.main_url,callback=self.parse,meta={'domain':d})


    def parse_item(self, response):
        # I need to get `Domain` object for all responses
```

Do you know how to do that? Moreover, this has another problem. It doesn't send the first (root) url response to `parse_item` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what is your end goal, but think you can do this, create dict `all_responses` and after each URL is scraped, put that into dictionary as `url` being the key.

You can use `self.all_responses["MY_LINK_HERE"]` to access any Domain object based on link.

```
class MainSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'main_spider' 
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_item', follow=True,),
    )

    all_responses = {}

    def start_requests(self):
        for d in Domain.objects.all():
            self.allowed_domains.append(d.name)
            yield scrapy.Request(d.main_url,callback=self.parse,meta={'domain':d})


    def parse_item(self, response):
        self.all_responses[response.url] = response.meta['domain']
```

I think do not use `Rule` class, instead use `LinkExtractor` so you have freedom of sending `meta` variable along with request.

or do this,

```
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
extractor = LinkExtractor(allow_domains="www.website.com")
links = extractor.extract_links(response)
for link in links:
        yield scrapy.Request(link.url, callback=self.my_callback)
```

Comment: Simply, I want to track which url belongs to which domain object so I can do something with this domain object. This is not possible for urls which were extracted using rule.

Comment: you know about `process_request` method of Middleware? each request goes through that method before scraping, and for sure, links scraped using Rule class also goes through that method, I know I am not telling you exact solution but just telling something because something may click in your mind

Comment: I know about process_request but I won't help probably. The point is that there will be no 'domain' object in meta if it's not from starting urls. I want to avoid parsing URL and looking for domain object in database.

Comment: can you tell me what `Domain.objects.all()` has?

Comment: Domain is a class and model of Django ORM. It represents a table. But it doesn't matter. It's the same like I'd want to send just name of the base start url through the meta.

Comment: `http://www.example.com`, `http://www.example.com/x`, `http://www.example.com/x/x/y/` all will have Domain object of similar to `http://www.example.com`'s one?

Comment: Yes. they have the same domain object since they were found or extracted from that domain.main_url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165173/discussion-between-umair-and-milano-slesarik).

Comment: Thanks, this seems reasonable, will check it and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the first problem, but to solve the second one, you can override method [`parse_start_url`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.CrawlSpider.parse_start_url) of `CrawlSpider` class.